# Tails of Fourier Transformed family of functions

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I am reading a [thesis](http://tumb1.biblio.tu-muenchen.de/publ/diss/ma/2004/lasser.pdf) where on page 39, Definition 4, $\epsilon$-oscillatory is defined as a property for a family of functions $\{f_{\epsilon}\}_{0<\epsilon<1}$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to have if $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\limsup_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\{\left|\xi\right|>R\}}\frac{1}{\epsilon^d}\left|\widehat{f_{\epsilon}}\left(\frac{\xi}{\epsilon}\right)\right|^2d\xi=0.$$

It is mentioned soon after that for this property to hold it suffices that the weak derivative $\{\epsilon\nabla f_{\epsilon}\}$ is bounded in $L^2$. I cannot connect the two. The most I could do was the following

$$\sup_{\epsilon}||\epsilon\nabla f_{\epsilon}||_{L^2}<C \implies \sup_{\epsilon}||\epsilon\widehat{\nabla f_{\epsilon}}||_{L^2}<C\implies\sup_{\epsilon}||\epsilon\xi \widehat{f_{\epsilon}}||_{L^2}<C$$

$$\implies \sup_{\epsilon}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{1}{\epsilon^d}\left|p\widehat{f_{\epsilon}}\left(\frac{p}{\epsilon}\right)\right|^2dp<C$$ after a change of variables $\epsilon\xi=p$. Could someone please help me in figuring out the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first displayed equation, the substitution $t=\frac{\xi}\varepsilon$ reduces us to show that 
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\limsup_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\{|t|>\frac R\varepsilon\}}|\widehat{f_\varepsilon}(t)|^2dt=0.$$
Rewriting 
$$\int_{\{|t|>\frac R\varepsilon\}}|\widehat{f_\varepsilon}(t)|^2dt=\int_{\{|t|>\frac R\varepsilon\}}|t|^2|\widehat{f_\varepsilon}(t)|^2\frac 1{|t|^2}dt,$$
and and noticing that over the set of integration, $\frac 1{|t|^2}\leqslant\frac{\varepsilon^2}{R^2}$, we get
$$\int_{\{|t|>\frac R\varepsilon\}}|\widehat{f_\varepsilon}(t)|^2dt\leqslant \frac{\varepsilon^2}{R^2}\int_{\Bbb R^d}|t|^2|\widehat{f_\varepsilon}(t)|^2dt\leqslant\frac 1{R^2}\sup_{\varepsilon}\lVert\varepsilon \xi\widehat f_{\varepsilon}\rVert^2.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know when I will learn all these tricks!